# Kafka - Offset and logSize

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I see the below details when looking up the ddetails of Kafka logs. Does this mean that there are a total of 17905513 messages out of which 17905510 have already been read and 3 are pending to be read?

```
Offset      logSize     Lag 
17905510    17905513    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost. Kafka saves the offset from time to time (it depends on settings). It doesn't save the offset after every message has been read or processed. Thus it may means that the Consumer haven't read the last three messages yet but it may also means that it has read all pending messages but the offset in ZK hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: Thanks Lukas! So the number below offset and logsize does refer to number of messages?

Comment: Yes, you are right and the comment must be at least 15 characters long :)

Comment: Thanks Lukas , it should definitely be more than 15 characters in length :--)